# Read nested JSON fields in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I have an API that returns some nested json data that I would like airflow to read. However, airflow is giving me an error saying that the nested fields are NULL. These fields are not NULL and I can see the json data in any manual get requests I make to the API.

How do I modify my pipeline in order to read these nested fields?

My API returns a JSON object like:

```
    {
    "email": "ronald@mcdonald.com",
    "first_name": "ronald",
    "last_name": "mcdonald",
    "permissions": {
        "make_burgers": true,
        "make_icecream": false,
        },
     }
```

My airflow pipeline object looks like:

```
class StaffPipeline(_DefaultPipeline):
    source_url = f'{config.MCDONALDS_BASE_URL}/staff'
    table_config = TableConfig(
        table_name='mcdonalds__staff',
        field_mapping=[
            ('email', sa.Column('email', sa.Text)),
            ('first_name', sa.Column('first_name', sa.Text)),
            ('last_name', sa.Column('last_name', sa.Text)),
            ('make_burgers', sa.Column('make_burgers', sa.Boolean)),
            ('make_icecream', sa.Column('make_icecream', sa.Boolean)),
        ],
        indexes=(LateIndex("email"), LateIndex("last_name")),
    )
```

My error message when trying to run this pipeline:

```
raise UnusedColumnError(error)
mcdonalds_data.operators.db_tables.UnusedColumnError: Column mcdonalds__staff_123456789.make_burgers only contains NULL values
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you have to use a nested strucutre in airflow like so:

```
class StaffPipeline(_DefaultPipeline):
    source_url = f'{config.MCDONALDS_BASE_URL}/staff'
    table_config = TableConfig(
        table_name='mcdonalds__staff',
        field_mapping=[
            ('email', sa.Column('email', sa.Text)),
            ('first_name', sa.Column('first_name', sa.Text)),
            ('last_name', sa.Column('last_name', sa.Text)),
            (
                ("permissions", "make_burgers"),
            sa.Column('make_burgers', sa.Boolean),
            ),
            (
                ("permissions", "make_icecream"),
            sa.Column('make_icecream', sa.Boolean),
            ),
        ],
        indexes=(LateIndex("email"), LateIndex("last_name")),
    )
```